# How to make payments in an expo-based React Native app?

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, expo, payment-gateway

I am making a React Native app using Expo and right now, I am researching on how to implement payments in the app. I have been doing this for a good while now, it doesn't seem like any payment gateway has a specific tool for React Native, much less for a non ejected expo project.

Has anyone ever found the solution to this problem? Should I eject expo in order to use the APIs from the usual gateways?

Right now, I followed a tutorial that created a backend using node.js to make payments through Paypal, but it's not quite working in its integration with React Native. I also know that Stripe has options for this, but in my country (Brazil), it doesn't seem to be available quite yet, and few people use it anyway, so I'm welcoming alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you have to eject from the managed workflow and use the bare workflow. Then the following module will help you :

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/

Which works both for Android and iOs according to the documentation.

In a managed app you cannot have in-app purchases as of today. You may use Stripe if my understanding is good, but only for external good (like buying a T-shirt, but not to unlock possibilities in your app).

Comment: am using this expo-in-app-purchases "https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/" but am not able to build the ios solution after installing this package am trying to build the solution but its failed?why?any help?